# mergExt: using merAV for audio recording only

Tags: audio-recording, livecode

is it possible to use LC ext mergAV to record just audio to save as AIFF or WAVE?
if it is, where can i find examples about?

tia.

re.mu.

Answer (score 1):

No there's two other options for audio recording. RunRev's example external rremicrophone (in the iOS Externals SDK) and my derivative mergMicrophone available at http://github.com/montegoulding/mergmicrophone and binaries are available from mergExt.com.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but i tried both with no luck. i use LC 6.6.1 business, on osx 10.8 (or 10.9) with xcode 5.1.1. the target of my app is ios 6.1 or later. when i try to compile my app i get a compilation error.
i tried with the original form lc sdk R14, and this is the error:
"linking for architecture armv7 failed: undefined symbol for architecture armv7: "___libinfoptr_rremicrophone" referenced from -u command line option. ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7. clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1"

same with yours (v.1.0.1) ("___libinfoptr_mergMicrophone")

Comment: oh, wait… i see there a v.1.04 available at mergext… i seeked for days, how could i miss that one?… anyway, it works! thank your very much, monte!

Comment: sorry, it'm me again. your ext works perfectly. i need just a final tip: is it possible to export the audio file in a format different from .caf, i.e. mp3, like rrevmicrophone did?